# loop through array elements as strings and convert them to sub arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, curl

I've been trying for hours  to solve this. I have an array loaded from a remote text file from a curl result. It is numerical data separated by spaces and pipes.  I ran the curl result through a series of preg_match to deal with some irregularities and separate the fields with commas.

the result with *print_r* looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => 
[1] => 18,3,1.28,4,1,1,0.97,16.9,25,0,0.58,9.7,8,0,0.55,12.6,37,0,0.23,6.5,99,,, 
[2] => 18,4,1.30,4,0,0,1.00,16.9,25,0,0.58,9.6,8,0,0.55,12.6,37,0,0.24,6.5,99,,, 
[3] => 18,5,1.32,4,0,1,1.03,16.9,24,0,0.57,9.6,8,0,0.54,12.6,37,0,0.25,6.4,98,,, 
[4] => 18,6,1.34,4,0,0,1.06,16.8,24,0,0.57,9.5,8,0,0.54,12.6,37,0,0.25,6.4,99,,, 
[5] => 18,7,1.36,5,0,0,0.67,16.0,35,0,0.56,9.2,7,0,0.55,12.6,36,0,0.25,6.4,99,,, 
[6] => 18,8,1.38,5,0,0,0.73,16.5,35,0,0.56,9.5,7,0,0.55,12.6,36,0,0.25,6.3,100,,, )
```

I want to convert the string elements by comma to sub arrays and loop through the entire array

Along with a bunch of other attempts the closest I have come to the desired result is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($done); $i++) {
    print_r (explode(',', $done[$i]));
  }
```

the result:

```
Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 3 [2] => 1.28 [3] => 4 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 0.97 [7] => 16.9 [8] => 25 [9] => 0 [10] => 0.58 [11] => 9.7 [12] => 8 [13] => 0 [14] => 0.55 [15] => 12.6 [16] => 37 [17] => 0 [18] => 0.23 [19] => 6.5 [20] => 99 [21] => [22] => [23] => ) Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 4 [2] => 1.30 [3] => 4 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 1.00 [7] => 16.9 [8] => 25 [9] => 0 [10] => 0.58 [11] => 9.6 [12] => 8 [13] => 0 [14] => 0.55 [15] => 12.6 [16] => 37 [17] => 0 [18] => 0.24 [19] => 6.5 [20] => 99 [21] => [22] => [23] => ) Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 5 [2] => 1.32 [3] => 4 [4] => 0 [5] => 1 [6] => 1.03 [7] => 16.9 [8] => 24 [9] => 0 [10] => 0.57 [11] => 9.6 [12] => 8 [13] => 0 [14] => 0.54 [15] => 12.6 [16] => 37 [17] => 0 [18] => 0.25 [19] => 6.4 [20] => 98 [21] => [22] => [23] => )... )
```

the desired result:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 3 [2] => 1.28 [3] => 4 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 0.97 [7] => ...)
     [1] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 4 [2] => 1.30 [3] => 4 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 1.00 [7] => ...) 
     [2] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 5 [2] => 1.32 [3] => 4 [4] => 0 [5] => 1 [6] => 1.03 [7] => ... )
 )
```

The goal:

```
 echo $done[0][0] . ' ' . $done[0][1] . ' ' ... . '<br />'
      $done[1][0] . ' ' . $done[1][1] . ' ' ... . '<br />';
```

or something like that.

Comment: "a series of preg_match" -- that doesn't sound efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ( $done as $d ) {
    if ( is_null( $d ) ) continue;
    $res[] = explode( ',', $d );
}
```

Try it first.

Comment: works perfectly. some explanation would help me see the errors of my ways. glad I made myself clear. thanks.

Comment: The only thing you were missing was assigning it back to a result array. You were using print_r on the individual exploded arrays. Load each array into the result array as a value and then print_r. Voila.